# how to use the query code in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

now i want to get the node title list,and show it on the term page. if i know the term id. how i can get the node title under this term id? thank you. eg:the term id is 2. drupal version is 6
this is the query,

```
  $query = "SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.nid =   tn.nid WHERE tn.tid = arg(2)";
```

but i don't know how to pager it and output it in list?

Comment: the taxnomy/term/2 page.

Comment: Where are you trying to run this? In a custom module? theme override? custom tpl file?

Comment: custom tpl file(page-taxnomy-term.tpl.php)

Comment: Is simply installing and using Views not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way would be a view, either as a block or page (who could replace the taxonomy term page). If you want code, something like this should work:

```
<?php
$items = array();
$result = pager_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.nid = tn.nid WHERE tn.tid = %d", arg(2), 0, 10);
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $items[] = l($row->title, 'node/' . $row->nid);
}

print theme('item_list', $items, t('Nodes in this category'));
print theme('pager');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT n.nid, n.title FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.nid =   tn.nid WHERE tn.tid = %d";
$results = db_query($query,arg(2));

// define table headers(th)
$header = array(
        array('data' => t('Node NID')),
        array('data' => t('Node Title')),   
      );

//define rows in table
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
  $rows[] = array ($row[nid],$row[title]);
}

//leave the theming to hands of Drupal
echo theme('table',$header,$rows);
```